# What are the minimum and maximum values for this function?

Tags: trigonometry, curves

I have to draw the graph of the flat curve

$$
x = \frac{a}{4*\cos^2(t) -3} \\ y= \frac{a* \tan t}{4*\cos^2(t) -3}  \\ \text{where } 
 \ \ a =0.2 ,\ t \in \  (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \ \backslash  \{-\pi/6, \pi/6\}
$$

I search on the internet more information about this curve but I did not find anything. For $x$ I think the minimum value is $\frac{0.2}{-3}$ since the *cosine function* is $0$ for  $-\pi/2 $. The curve's name is trisectrix of Longchamps. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Polar coordinates : 
$$\begin{cases}
x=\rho\cos(t)=\frac{a}{4\cos^2(t) -3}=\frac{a}{\cos(3t)}\cos(t)\\
y=\rho\sin(t)=\frac{a \tan t}{4*\cos^2(t) -3}=\frac{a}{\cos(3t)}\sin(t)
\end{cases} 
\quad\implies\quad \rho=\frac{a}{\cos(3t)}$$

because $\cos(3t)=\cos(t)(4\cos^2(t) -3)$

This is the equation of the "equilateral trifoil" or "Longchamps trisectrix".

For properties see: https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/trefleequilatere/trefleequilatere.shtml

Comment: What happend with tan t?

Comment: What do you mean ? Nothing precial happen. This is usual for this kind of equation in polar coordinates.